# Getting a color from the CSS class using prototype

Tags: javascript, css, prototypejs

Lets say I have a couple of CSS classes:

```
.tickup { color: green; }
.tickdn { color: red; }
.tick { color: black; }
```

Then I have JavaScript (which is using Prototype) that needs to dynamically change color of another element. That's easy - $('element').style.color = 'red'. But the thing is that the page is skinned, so my only way is to look up a class definition, one of three above, and get the color to set the element to.

Is there a way for me to do something like: findCssClass(tickup).color ?

Thanks!

Comment: And can you not just apply the special class? Like `$('element').className += " tickup";`

Comment: Cannot really since those colors need to be given to scriptaculous for the effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [getStyle](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/getStyle):

```
$$('.tick').each(function (element) {
  element.getStyle('color');
});
```

Comment: That doesn't work and requires me to have an element with that style. Looks like there's no way of finding out that information directly.

Comment: Have you thought about adding an element to the page that is hidden and read the style?

Comment: @epascarello - yes, but prototype api says that will cause null values in Safari.

Comment: @Daniil - I apologize, I see now what you are saying. There are some jQuery libraries that are supposed to do it, but I never got any of them to work properly. None of them could handle the `:hover` psuedoclass. However, I believe they worked other than that. Take a look at http://jquery.com/plugins/project/Rule to see if it does what you need.

Comment: @epascarello - I've used your suggestion, but instead of having a hidden element, I have a span with desired class that contains &nbsp; inside. Then read it using $('refTickup').getStyle('color') once on 'startup' and that's that. Many thanks! If you add your comment as an answer, I'll accept that.